# PyTorch: Can I group batches by length?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, huggingface-datasets

I am working on an ASR project, where I use a model from HuggingFace (`wav2vec2`). My goal for now is to move the training process to PyTorch, so I am trying to recreate everything that HuggingFace’s `Trainer()` class offers.

One of these utilities is the ability to group batches by length and combine this with dynamic padding (via a data collator). To be honest however, I am not sure how to even begin this in PyTorch.

The inputs in my case are 1-D arrays that represent the raw waveform of a .wav file. So before training I need to ensure that arrays of similar size will be batched together. Do I need to create a custom Dataloader class and alter it, so that every time it gives me batch sizes of lengths as close as possible?

An idea I had, was to somehow sort the data from shortest to longest (or the opposite), and each time extract batch_size samples from them. This way, the first batch will consist of samples with the biggest lengths, the second batch will have the second biggest lengths, etc.

Nevertheless, I am not sure how to approach this implementation. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not apply a random fixed crop on all your inputs?

Comment: You mean, set my input size to something standard and crop/reduce the size of the arrays who are larger?

Comment: Considering my inputs are waveforms that must be matched to transcribed text, removing a random part of their inputs (cropping) will be tough because I dont know what part of the text it corresponds to so I can remove it as well. Also, since the data are audio files, their durations vary a lot, and I want to avoid the fixed overall size of the data. As mentioned in the post, I am performing dynamic padding as well. So I dont mind large inputs, I just want them to be matched with other similar size inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way of going about this is by using a *batch sampler* and implementing a `collate_fn` for your dataloader that will perform the dynamic padding on your batch elements.

Take this basic dataset:

```
class DS(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, files):
        super().__init__()
        self.len = len(files)
        self.files = files

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.files[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
```

Initialized with some random data:

```
>>> file_len = np.random.randint(0, 100, (16*6))
>>> files = [np.random.rand(s) for s in file_len]
>>> ds = DS(files)
```

Start by defining your batch sampler, this is essentially an iterable returning batches of indices to be used by the data loader to retrieve the elements from the dataset. As you explained we can just sort the lengths and construct the different batches from this sort:

```
>>> batch_size = 16
>>> batches = np.split(file_len.argsort()[::-1], batch_size)
```

We should have elements that are close to each other in length.

We can implement a [`collate_fn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#automatic-batching-default) function to assemble the batch elements and integrate dynamic padding. This is basically putting an additional user-defined layer right between the dataset and the dataloader. The goal is to find the longest element in the batch and pad all other elements with the correct number of `0`s:

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    longest = max([len(x) for x in batch])
    s = np.stack([np.pad(x, (0, longest - len(x))) for x in batch])
    return torch.from_numpy(s)
```

Then you can intialize a data loader:

```
>>> dl = DataLoader(dataset=ds, batch_sampler=batches, collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

And try iterating, as you can see we get batches of decreasing lengths:

```
>>> for x in dl:
...   print(x.shape)
torch.Size([6, 99])
torch.Size([6, 93])
torch.Size([6, 83])
torch.Size([6, 76])
torch.Size([6, 71])
torch.Size([6, 66])
torch.Size([6, 57])
...
```

---

This method has some flaws though, for instance, the distribution of elements will always be the same. This means you will always get the same batches in the same order of appearance. This is because this method is based on the sorting of elements in the dataset based on their length, there is no variability in the creation of the batches. You can reduce this effect by shuffling the batches (e.g. by wrapping `batches` inside a [`RandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.RandomSampler)). However, as I said, the batches' content will remain the same throughout the training which might lead to some problems.

*Do note the use of `batch_sampler` in your data loader is mutually exclusive options `batch_size`, `shuffle`, and `sampler`!*

Comment: Ivan, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Upon thinking more of my idea, I had reached the same conclusion as you. Although it is technically a solution, the batches' content will have to remain the same throughout the training process. I am not sure yet how much this can hurt the model's training, so I will have to think a bit more about that. Other than that, your code and answer is extremely valuable. I feel like the answer might be in creating a more detailed custom sampler. Do you have any ideas about that? Again, thanks a ton.

Comment: If you allow the sampler to pick from larger sets of similar-sized elements, then with a big dataset you can manage to create enough variability in the sampled batches. In practice, you would segment the sorted array of indices into subsets of similar size: you will have to decide on the size and variance of those subsets. Then when sampling pick one of the subset, then pick `batch_size` elements from that subset. By shuffling the batch around, you will have the desired randomness in your sampling. Ultimately, you will have to try it out with a training experiment and see!

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot for your advice. Have a nice dayyy

Comment: Just did! Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Ivan's answer, there are two steps to creating the DataLoader:

1. You need to provide a `BatchSampler` object that provides the indices of the samples in each batch. (I think that this only works with map-style datasets).
2. You need to provide a `collate_fn` function that will do the padding on the fly, so you don't have to commit to a specific sequence length beforehand.

For the batch sampler there is actually this neat trick: Say you want to have a batch with size `B` and have sequences with relatively equal lengths. You draw random super-batches of size `100*B`, you sort these super-batches and then you yield 100 batches with the requested property. Using this procedure you will have different batches on every run, because you are not sorting the entire data set, but only small chunks from it which are drawn at random.
Here is some example code:

```py
class BatchSampler:
    def __init__(self, lengths, batch_size):
        # ...

    def __iter__(self):
    size, step = len(self.lengths), 100*self.batch_size
    indices = list(range(size))
    random.shuffle(indices)
    for i in range(0, size, step): 
        pool = sorted(indices[i:i+step], key=lambda x: self.lengths[x])
        for j in range(0, len(pool), self.batch_size):
            yield pool[j:j+self.batch_size]
```

For the collate_fn you can use a utility func provided by the torch library: [torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html)

For a full working example please see this [blog post](https://pi-tau.github.io/posts/transformer/#tricks-batching-by-length) of mine or this [project on github](https://github.com/pi-tau/transformer/blob/3d4bbc055dd695eccd7ca97d6646d6a81a239cb9/run.py#L43) (also by me).

Answer (score 0):

I developed another Sampler based on @Ivan's answer. Here, the order of data with similar sizes is perturbed by adding random noise.  I'm not sure if this works under DDP though.

```py
class LengthBatchSampler(Sampler):

    def __init__(self, data, batch_size, size_fn, shuffle=True, drop_last=False, perturb_sigma=0.3, seed=42):
        """

        Args:
            data:
            batch_size (int):
            size_fn:  a function that will be used as size_fn(data[i]) to get the size of i-th data
            shuffle (bool):
            drop_last (bool):
            perturb_sigma (float): the sigma of normal noise on the size values, used to perturb the data order
                set to 0 to disable
            seed (int):
        """

        super().__init__()

        if not isinstance(batch_size, int) or isinstance(batch_size, bool) or \
                batch_size <= 0:
            raise ValueError(f"batch_size should be a positive integer value, but got batch_size={batch_size}")
        if not isinstance(shuffle, bool):
            raise ValueError(f"shuffle should be a boolean value, but got shuffle={drop_last}")
        if not isinstance(drop_last, bool):
            raise ValueError(f"drop_last should be a boolean value, but got drop_last={drop_last}")
        if not (isinstance(perturb_sigma, float) and perturb_sigma >= 0):
            raise ValueError(f"perturb_sigma should be a positive float value, or 0 to disable perturbation, "
                             f"but got perturb_sigma={batch_size}")

        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.size_fn = size_fn

        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.drop_last = drop_last
        self.perturb_sigma = perturb_sigma

        generator = torch.Generator()
        generator.manual_seed(seed)
        self.generator = generator

        l = len(self.data) / self.batch_size
        num_batches = math.floor(l) if self.drop_last else math.ceil(l)
        self.num_batches = num_batches

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_batches

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
        sizes = torch.FloatTensor([self.size_fn(i) for i in self.data])

        noise = torch.randn_like(sizes) * self.perturb_sigma

        sizes = sizes + noise

        sizes = sizes[:self.batch_size * self.num_batches]

        batches = torch.chunk(torch.argsort(sizes), len(self))

        if self.shuffle:
            bi = torch.randperm(len(self), generator=self.generator)
        else:
            bi = range(len(self))

        for i in bi:
            yield batches[i]
```